# How to correctly use Prometheus Histogram from java client to track size rather than latency?

Tags: performance, monitoring, prometheus

I have an API that that processes collections. 
The execution time of this API is related to the collection size (the larger the collection, the more it will take).

I am researching how can I do this with prometheus but am unsure whether I am doing things correctly (documentation is a bit lacking in this area).

the first thing I did is define a Summary metric to measure execution time of the API. I am using the canonical rate(sum)/rate(count) as explained [here](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/histograms/).

Now, since I know that the latency may be affected by the size of the input, I also want to overlay the request *size* on the avg execution time. Since I dont want to measure each possible size, I figured I'd use a histogram. Like so:

```
Histogram histogram = Histogram.build().buckets(10, 30, 50)
        .name("BULK_REQUEST_SIZE")
        .help("histogram of bulk sizes to correlate with duration")
        .labelNames("method", "entity")
        .register();
```

**Note**: the term 'size' does *not* relate to the size in bytes but to the *length* of the collection that needs to be processed. 2 items, 5 items, 50 items...

and in the execution I do (simplified):

```
@PUT
void process(Collection<Entity> entitiesToProcess, string entityName){
   Timer t = summary.labels("PUT_BULK", entityName).startTimer()

      // process...

   t.observeDuration();
   histogram.labels("PUT_BULK", entityName).observe(entitiesToProcess.size())
}
```

Question:

- Later when I am looking at the BULK_REQUEST_SIZE_bucket in Grafana, I see that all buckets have the same value, so clearly I am doing something wrong.
- Is there a more canonical way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct (though `bulk_request_size_bytes` would be a better metric name).

The problem is likely that you've suboptimal buckets, as 10, 30 and 50 bytes are pretty small for most request sizes. I'd try larger bucket sizes that cover more typical values.

Comment: Thanks Brian!

But the term 'size' does not relate to the size in bytes but to the length of the collection that needs to be processed. 2 items, 5 items, 50 items...

edited the question.

Comment: The issue is still with your choice of buckets, try larger values.

Comment: I will. What about the approach itself? Would it be better to have a summary where the label is range of a bucket? for example: 
Summary.build().labels("size range", "method") and than simply measure durations of these dimensions?

Comment: I think the approach is fine.

Comment: I realized the problem - I misunderstood the histogram data. I *expected* the buckets to represent disjoint ranges (0-10), (10-30), (30-50), (50,+inf) whereas they represent <= ranges. So when I observe a size of, say 6- it bumps the counter in all buckets because 6<10 and 6<30 and 6<50 and 6<+inf. Is there a way to get the data on the disjoint ranges anyway?

Comment: I think I got it - I can subtract the buckets like:

BULK_REQUEST_SIZE{le="20"} - ignoring(le) BULK_REQUEST_SIZE{le="10"}. This should give me the increase in the range (10,20) if I understad correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's the way it works. It's intended that you use histograms mainly with `histogram_quantile` which deals with this.

Comment: @brian-brazil could you give an example of how Vitaliy's solution is converted to a query with `histogram_quantile`?

Comment: @Pithikos or someone else, do you finally find the query please ?