# Prometheus histogram buckets with ranges

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-java

I have a basic histogram that measures some dummy duration:

```
    Histogram histogram = Histogram.build().name(name).help((String) metricData.get(HELP)).register(registry);

    Histogram.Timer timer = histogram.startTimer();
    logger.info("Sleeps for 1 milli");
    Thread.sleep(1);
    histogram.observe(timer.observeDuration());
```

My Prometheus histograms looks as follows:

```
HELP myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test histogram with some info about something
TYPE myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test histogram
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.005"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.01"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.025"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.05"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.075"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.1"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.25"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.5"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="0.75"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="1"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="2.5"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="5"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="7.5"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="10"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_bucket{instance="",job="myJob",le="+Inf"} 2
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_sum{instance="",job="latrodectus"} 0.006341000000000001
myJob_histogram_no_buckets_test_count{instance="",job="latrodectus"} 2
```

I understand why all my buckets values Increased, but I don't understand two things:

1. I expected the values to be 1, what am I doing wrong in my source code? why all values are 2?
2. How can I set the buckets to use ranges, instead of <=?

I saw this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46277332/how-to-correctly-use-prometheus-histogram-from-java-client-to-track-size-rather) but I don't understand the solution

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I expected the values to be 1, what am I doing wrong in my source code? why all values are 2?

You observed twice. If you're using `observeDuration` you don't also need `observe`.

> How can I set the buckets to use ranges, instead of <=?

You can't, this is how `histogram_quantile` expects the buckets to be.

Comment: Hi @brian-brazil, there is no way to achieve this kind of metric?

Answer (score 0):

I think one way you can achieve this, is through regex. For example,

```regex
le=~"([1-9]+)\\..*"
```

will give you all values that are greater than 0.9999